# Scrollable Background Image in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, frontend

I'm trying to add an image in the background of a screen which is very long and I want the image to be scrollable. Please give suggestions/code snippets for me to achieve this.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `overflow-y: scroll`?

Comment: Have you tried the ScrollView tag?

Answer (score 1):

Just put the image inside a ScrollView like this

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <ScrollView >
        <ImageBackground
          style={{
            height: 1000,
            width: '100%',
          }}
          source={{
            uri: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkNF4.jpg',
          }}
        />
      </ScrollView>
    </>
  );
}
```

Let me know if it worked